# how to get the line number having a specific string in a txt file - matlab

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a txt file that has a lot of content and in this file there is a lot of "include" word and I want to get data from all three lines after that.

myFile.txt:
"-include:

-6.5  6.5

sin(x^2)

diff

-include

-5 5

cos(x^4)

diff"

How do I get this data in an array?

Comment: you need to determine where the "include"s are?

Comment: yes,but i want  to get the data after the "include" string.for example get -6.5 ,6.5 ,sin(x^2) and diff as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example (first include has `:` at the end, second one doesn't) you could use something like this.

```
fID = fopen('myFile.txt'); % Open the file for reading
textString = textscan(fID, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n'); % Read all lines into cells
fclose(fID); % Close the file for reading
textString = textString{1}; % Use just the contents on the first cell (each line inside will be one cell)
includeStart = find(contains(textString,'include'))+1; % Find all lines with the word include. Add +1 to get the line after
includeEnd = [includeStart(2:end)-2; length(textString)]; % Get the position of the last line before the next include (and add the last line in the file)
parsedText = cell(length(includeStart), 1); % Create a new cell to store the output
% Loop through all the includes and concatenate the text with strjoin
for it = 1:length(includeStart)
  parsedText{it} = strjoin(textString(includeStart(it):includeEnd(it)),'\n');
  % Display the output
  fprintf('Include block %d:\n', it);
  disp(parsedText{it});
end
```

Which results in the following output:

```
Include block 1:
-6.5 6.5
sin(x^2)
diff
Include block 2:
-5 5
cos(x^4)
diff
```

You can tune the loop to suit your needs. If you just want line numbers, use `includeStart` and `includeEnd` variables.

Comment: Thanks Javier Very much,what should I do to put data in separate variables?example:i want to put -6.5 , 6.5 , sin(x^2) and diff to separate variables.

Comment: dear Javier Orlandi,this code generates a 2*1 cell array i want to have a 4*2 cell array that give me all 4 data after "inculde" string in cell arrays,so that when i call for example parsedText{1}{1} give me -6.5 .thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If you change the first line of the loop for `parsedText{it} = textString(includeStart(it):includeEnd(it));` that will do the trick. Please note that we split the text based on line breaks (if you want to split the first -6.5 and 6.5) you might have to change the textscan line